# How can i solve this error: llegal string offset 'text'?

Tags: php, string, text, offset

I have this code :

```
if(strlen($userdata->yim['text']) > 2 && !isset($_POST['step1']) ){

    $GLOBALS['error']       = 1;
    $GLOBALS['error_type']  = "tip";
    $GLOBALS['error_msg']   = $userdata->yim['text'];}
```

I read about this error on this site but i have no ideea how to apply the fix on my particular code. I`m sorry if i repost the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer but as i said, i have no idea how to do that. My dev left me with a few errors to troubleshoot and i have no idea what i`m doing.

Comment: What line is it? Is it the `if` statement or the last line?

Comment: Is `$userdata->yim` a class->function() call? If so your PHP version might not support the syntax or you might need to do `$userdata->yim()['text']` instead.

Comment: monkeyzeus, i appreciate your answer but i`m not a programmer. would you mind dumbing the answer for my level ? i tried if(strlen($userdata->yim()['text']) > 2 && !isset($_POST['step1']) ){ in my editor but it says the syntax is wrong. I apologize for the bother.

Comment: I'll post an answer because it will be easier to understand. By the way since you're new you can do `@MonkeyZeus` to get my attention specifically because otherwise I don't know you commented unless I happen to check your question after a few minutes =)

Comment: For a better experience on this site overall please check out http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Try doing: `var_dump($userdata->yim);` to verify if yim does in fact exist and contains the key 'text'.

Or even just `var_dump($userdata);`

Comment: Just before your line that does the `if` test, try doing the var_dump followed immediately by `die;` just to output the contents of $userdata to the screen for debugging.

Comment: Tried that, no change. same result. i might be doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`$userdata->yim['text']` is not set, so you should check for that first:

```
if(isset($userdata->yim['text']) && strlen($userdata->yim['text']) > 2 && !isset($_POST['step1']) ){
```

However, if that section of code relies on that value, something is wrong before that and this will just hide that problem.

Comment: This worked. It did hide the error but as you predicted, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug this you will need to utilize `print_r()` so that you can see the contents of your object or array:

```
// see what $userdata contains - update your question with the results of the line below
echo '<div style="background-color:white; padding:15px;"><pre>'.print_r($userdata, true).'</pre></div>';

// see what $userdata->yim contains - update your question with the results of the line below as well
echo '<div style="background-color:white; padding:15px;"><pre>'.print_r($userdata->yim, true).'</pre></div>';

if(strlen($userdata->yim['text']) > 2 && !isset($_POST['step1']))
{
    $GLOBALS['error']       = 1;
    $GLOBALS['error_type']  = "tip";
    $GLOBALS['error_msg']   = $userdata->yim['text'];
}
```